# sprite kit - partially mask sprite layer

Tags: sprite-kit, swift3, 2d-games

i have a 2-d fruit ninja style iOS (swift 3) game where an animal eats the "enemy" sprite.

currently i can detect a collision between the mouth and the enemy and cause the enemy to disappear with an animation.

however, i would like to implement a more realistic effect where the enemy sprite disappears into the mouth by occluding an increasing portion of the enemy as it moves further into the mouth.

i tried using combinations of masks and layering, but they were hacky and compromise the UX. what would be the most elegant approach to achieving this effect?

current/non-preferred example:
[image: current]

ideal/preferred example:
[image: preferred]

Comment: Can the penguins ever miss the mouth, and fall to either side?

Comment: Yes. It plays pretty much like fruit ninja

Comment: You do a SKCropNode with a mask of the mouth with the upper part of the dogs face.  When the penguin is in the mouth, you add it to the crop node, when it is not in the mouth, you remove it from the crop node

Comment: Could you please go into a bit more detail. I'm having trouble conceptualizing your proposed solution?